# Getting a form to use multiple queries as record source

Tags: vba, ms-access

So I've been working on the next step of my program, which consist on two buttons each of one is supposed to open a treatment form based on data that is asked to the user.

After searching a bit on the internet i found that the following syntax should have made the trick

```
Forms!FormName.RecordSource = Query
```

It didn't.

My actual code is as follows:

```
Private Sub BQueryDate_Click()
On Error GoTo Err_BQueryDate_Click

Dim stDocName As String
Dim stLinkCriteria As String

Forms!ShowTreatment.RecordSource = QueryDate
stDocName = "ShowTreatment"

DoCmd.OpenForm stDocName, , , stLinkCriteria

Exit_BQueryDate_Click:
Exit Sub

Err_BQueryDate_Click:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume Exit_BQueryDate_Click

End Sub
```

"Showtreatment" used to be a form that showed every record for the table Treatment, but now I want to switch between the queries QueryDate and QueryHospital so I can sort the data.

The thing is that with that code when I click the button access tells me that "ShowTreatment" is not found on the Form list.

I think that it can be caused by the recordsource line not being on the right place, but couldn't made it to work anyway, and I did not found any example of it applied to my concrete case since every one I found was trying to use it on a subform, and I need to change a normal form.

Edit:
Ok, dumb question cause I found something similar in here. (If only I had searched for 3 pages more)

[Access VBA: Set record source of form on button click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6919639/access-vba-set-record-source-of-form-on-button-click/6931190#6931190)

I'll give it a try.

Nope. Now it just ask me for date AND hospital name. I think I'm missing something important here.

The code

```
Forms.Item(MostTratamiento).RecordSource = "ConsultaQueryHospital"
```

Doesn't give me an error message (it even ask me about the hospital name) but doesn't change the record source either so it just shows the default.

Comment: What's QueryDate, that is undefined in BQueryDate_Click(), or it is a text like control in a form?

Comment: QueryDate is a Query i have created which asks the user for 2 dates and sets a range of dates to show treatments. I also tried adding "Query." before it but I think that did not work either.

Comment: So we use "QueryDate" - double quoted.

Comment: And I did have them but seeing how it wasn't working I just removed the quotes just in case and forgot to re-add them when I posted the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
Private Sub BQueryDate_Click()
  On Error GoTo Err_BQueryDate_Click

  Dim stDocName As String
  Dim stLinkCriteria As String

  stDocName = "ShowTreatment"

  ' we open first the form:
  DoCmd.OpenForm stDocName, , , stLinkCriteria

  ' we then set up it's RecordSource:
  Forms!ShowTreatment.RecordSource = "QueryDate"

Exit_BQueryDate_Click:
Exit Sub

Err_BQueryDate_Click:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume Exit_BQueryDate_Click

End Sub
```

Comment: Ok. that worked as a charm. In the end was what I was suspecting about the line being out of position. Many thanks.